# What do Weka's different test options mean?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, cross-validation, training-data

So I've recently started using Weka and there are several test options when building a tree with, for example, J48. The following are the options, including my undestanding of them:

1. **Use training set** - I know just that it's highly optimistic and not necessarily useful. Even [Weka's documentation at 2.1.5](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/Witten_et_al_2016_appendix.pdf) isn't being all too specific.
2. **Supplied test set** - Pretty self-explanatory, you supply it a test set.
3. **Cross-Validation** - I understood it by reading [this](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pat/706_98/ln/node119.html) short example.
4. **Percentage Split** - I assume it means partitioning the data set into two sets of a certain percentage, one set for training and one for testing.

What I want to know is what exactly is the training set (first option) and what it does. Where does it get this training set from and what data does it test on exactly? And also if you could correct my understanding of the rest, if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option simply means "use all data loaded to run this algorithm". You choose this

- to try things out,
- to have a first look at the results-section in the output,
- to check the performance/run duration,
- to check if Weka's output matches the implementation of the same algorithm of a different software, say R or Matlab.
- ...

Comment: So am I correct to understand that it first trains on all the data, then tests on all the data? i.e. it's using the same exact data for both training and testing, which would explain why I'm seeing 100% accuracy with some data I'm trying, while it drops to like 70% with 10-fold Cross-Validation

Comment: Yes indeed. You'd get 100% accuracy with this option. 10fold cross validation is the recommended option for getting more realistic results. They use this in the Weka MOOCs all the time.

Comment: why is that 10fold cross validation is the recommended? In my case, I've tested with 0fold, 2fold, 5fold, 10fold, 20fold, 99999fold. The first and the last, as expected, didnt work. The others, had the same percentage in the correctly classified strategies, 90%. The root relative squared error is max in 2fold, around 70%, whereas 5fold and 20fold are 60% and 10fold 61% @knb

Comment: obviously it deends on your sample size. if sample size is small, then 5-fold cross validation may also be a good choice because the slices/folds still have a more suitable minimum size. Above 10 there is not much difference.

Comment: When can one say is a good / best choice? Sample is small yes

Comment: if your data set contains 100 samples, there are 2 extremes: (1) you can split it into 2 sets, training set and test set. This is wasteful and will have high bias (your 2 means, say, may be very different). (2) If you split it into 99 folds and use one for testing, and average the 99 fits, this  tends to have high variance. So K = 5 to 10 provides as good compromise for this bias-variance tradeoff. (see  ISLR book)

Comment: accordingly to this example [ http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html ] , he says "At small k's the jaggedness and islands are signs of variance. The locations of the islands and the exact curves of the boundaries will change radically as new data is gathered. On the other hand, at large k's the transition is very smooth so there isn't much variance, but the lack of a match to the boundary line is a sign of high bias." which seems like the opposite of what you said...

Comment: Just briefly read the linked blogpost, but I think he talks about k-Nearest neighbor Algorithm and the visualizations of decision boundaries. That's a different thing I was talking about. My "K" is different, K-Fold Cross-Validation. I could have called it n-fold cross validation but by convention n is often used for the number of measurements/rows. My reference was from ISLR sec 5-1-4 http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf. - I'll stop here; this thread is getting too long.

Comment: appreciated for your time @knb , really

Answer (score 1):

Option one is:

test set = training set

The resulting scores will be prone to overfitting of course, and that is why its "highly optimistic and not necessarily useful".